# Why does my image get automatically re-scaled?

Tags: c#

I had to start making a jigsaw/image puzzle today in class, which went fine, except for the fact that my image kept/keeps re-scaling by itself.

The image itself is 300*300, but when running the code it becomes 192*192, even though I use the image's own size to declare the size.

The code consists of:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Bitmap Bmp;
    private Point BmpLoc;

    int x = 0, y = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(Form1_Paint);
    }

    private void showButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bmp = new Bitmap("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\img.png");
        BmpLoc = new Point(0, 0);
        Rectangle R = new Rectangle(BmpLoc, Bmp.Size);
        int noot = Bmp.Size.Height;
        label3.Text = noot.ToString();

        this.Invalidate(R);
    }
    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Bmp != null)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(Bmp, BmpLoc);
        }
    }
```

As you can see, it takes the Bitmap Size for the rectangle's size, so shouldn't it just show 300*300?

Thank you in advance for answering

Comment: Hm. How do you check that is ends up as 192px on the screen? Screenshot? What is Bmp.Size at runtime?

Comment: @usr Part of the jigsaw puzzle assignment was to add the location of the cursor, so I can see on what pixel the cursor is. Screenshot: http://imageshack.us/a/img9/7690/37798533.png the white number is the Bmp's height

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of the DPI of the image. You can use [`Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawimageunscaled.aspx):

```
e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(Bmp, BmpLoc);
```

You can check the DPI (resolution) of the image using [`HorizontalResolution`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.horizontalresolution.aspx) and [`VerticalResolution`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.verticalresolution.aspx) properties. Usually the screen has a resolution of 96 DPI (dots per inch). However this is configurable in windows. If the resolution of the image is something other that this, the image is scaled to maintain its screen size.

Comment: Yes, this worked!  
I changed the resolution(was set to 146 for no reason) to 96 and it worked fine. Thanks for helping!